# Error in getting block in a template

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks, custom-block

I am a magento beginner and need help with creating a new custom block.
Basically, I just want the block to show "hello" if it is called.

1. Module installation xml file, **app/etc/modules/MyExtensions_HelloBlock.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
       <modules>
         <MyExtensions_HelloBlock>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyExtensions_HelloBlock>
      </modules>
   </config>
   ```
2. Module configuration xml file, **app/code/local/MyExtensions/HelloBlock/etc/config.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <config>
       <modules>
        <MyExtensions_HelloBlock>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MyExtensions_HelloBlock>
      </modules>
      <global>
        <blocks>
            <helloblock>
                <class>MyExtensions_HelloBlock_Block</class>
            </helloblock>
        </blocks> 
      </global>
   </config>
   ```
3. Block class, **app/code/local/MyExtensions/HelloBlock/Hello.php**.

   ```
   <?php
   class MyExtensions_HelloBlock_Block_Hello extends  Mage_Core_Block_Template 
   {    
      public function hello()
      {
      echo "hello";
      }
   }
   ```
4. Template file for the block, **app/design/frontend/default/default/template/helloblock/hello.phtml**

   ```
   <?php
    $this->hello();
   ?>
   ```

Then I call my new block like this in the template "app/design/frontend/venedor/default/template/page/1column.phtml"

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('helloblock/hello')->setTemplate('helloblock/hello.phtml')->toHtml();
```

**Result:**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on boolean in
>   /app/design/frontend/venedor/default/template/page/1column.phtml
>   on line 58

I was following this [tutorial](http://www.codexpedia.com/magento/magento-create-a-new-block-and-add-it-to-a-template/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added wrong block class, it should be  `app/code/local/MyExtensions/HelloBlock/Block/Hello.php` instead of  `app/code/local/MyExtensions/HelloBlock/Hello.php`

You are missing **Block** directory in the module

Comment: I still get `Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on boolean`

Comment: did you moved your block in file inside `Block` directory?

Comment: "Hello.php" is now at "app/code/local/MyExtensions/HelloBlock/Block/Hello.php"

Comment: everything seems right, please check for typo and clear cache once

Comment: Yes you were correct... I accidendially named the folders "MyExtension" instead of "MyExtensions". Thanks!! :)